# Exporting friend lists of the people appearing in a search result (FB)

Tags: facebook

Good Morning

I would like to find a person on Facebook with the following algorithm:

1. typing the given name of this person in the search bar, because that is all I know
2. going through the profile pages of every person in the search result list
3. opening the friend list of these people one-by-one (if public)
4. then check if they are friend with one specific person (mutual friend)

Is it possible to automate this process, if then, how?

So basically I just want to know which person from the search result list has this mutual friend on his friend list. This is necessary because the friend list of the mutual acquaintance is hidden.

Your kind help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for 2 reasons:

- Scraping is not allowed on Facebook, you MUST use the Graph API - if there is no way with the Graph API, don't do it.
- Users (and friends) are not available in any way if they did not specifically authorize your App - for privacy reasons. You can only get friends of users who authorized your App too.

Comment: thank you but if I can manually click and search through peoples friend lists, then it can be automated too. I understand that facebook does not want us to do it, but I dont really care.

Comment: that is not how it works. just because you can do stuff on facebook.com, does not mean you are allowed to automated it, and especially not scrape it without explicit permission.

Comment: facebook exploits people, but people should refrain for illicit activities on facebook?

Comment: yes, if you want to use a platform, you have to accept and live by their rules. no matter what you think about them. why use a platform if you dont like what they do? ;) - anyway, that's quite off topic.